# Tricky substring problems

Tags: c++, regex, substring, getline

I'm having a problem with substrings, I have a string in the format below I'm 
currently using getline.

```
Richard[12345/678910111213141516] was murdered
```

What I have been using is `find_last_of` and `find_first_of` to get the positions in between the brackets and forward slashes to retrieve each field. I have this working and functional but I have ran into a problem. The name field can be 32 characters in length, and can contain / and [] so when I finally ran into a user with a URL for his name it did not like that. The numbers are also random on a per user basis. I'm retrieving each field from the string, the name and the two identifying numbers.

Another string can look like this, so I would be grabbing 6 total substrings.

```
Richard[12345/678910111213141516] was murdered by Ralph[54321/161514131211109876]
```

Which is just a just another huge mess, what I was thinking about doing was starting from the back and moving to the front, but if the second name field (Ralph) contains any / or [] its going to ruin the count for retrieving the first part. Any insight would be helpful. Thank you.

In a nutshell. how do I account for these.

Names can also contain any alpha / numerical and special character.

```
Richard///[][][12345/678910111213141516] was murdered by Ralph[/[54321/161514131211109876]
```

The end result would be 6 substrings containing this.

- Richard///[][]
- 12345
- 678910111213141516
- Ralph[/
- 54321
- 161514131211109876

Regex has been mentioned to me, but I don't know if it would be better suited for the task or not, I included the tag so someone more experienced with it might answer/comment.

Comment: Poor Richard :( - So, you want to get the name in a string, and the ID in another?

Comment: No. I can do this, but I cannot account for the randomness of the name of the person, their name could be Richard/////[[[[[]][[] and the way I'm currently doing this searching for those cannot account for that. What I'm wondering is how can I account for such a name.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear about that Ill edit the post.

Comment: Names can not have numbers? Strictly?

Comment: Names can contain any alpha / numerical and special character, which is why I didn't think Regex would work.

Comment: So, a possible string could be: `Ri[1231]ch[3/24]][]ard[12345/678910111213141516] was murdered`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes, I believe so, I have to check manually. Edit : Yes they can.

Comment: It is still unclear: how do you want to store different people data?  Please check if [this code is what you are looking for](http://ideone.com/McA716).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex way to obtain all the values:

```
string str = "Richard///[][][12345/678910111213141516] was murdered by Ralph[/[54321/161514131211109876]";
regex rgx1(R"(([A-Z]\w*\s*\S*)\[(\d+)?(?:\/(\d+))?\])");
smatch smtch;
while (regex_search(str, smtch, rgx1)) {
        std::cout << "Name: " << smtch[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ID1: " << smtch[2] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ID2: " << smtch[3] << std::endl;
        str = smtch.suffix().str();
    }
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/McA716)

The regex `(\S*)\[(\d+)?(?:/(\d+))?\]` matches:

- `(\S*)` - (Group 1) 0 or more non-whitespace symbols, *as many as possible*.
- `\[` - an opening square bracket (must be escaped as it is a special character in regex reserved for character classes)
- `(\d+)?` - (Group 2) 1 or more digits (optional group, can be empty)
- `(?:/(\d+))?` - non-capturing optional group matching

  - `/` - literal `/`
  - `(\d+)` - (Group 3) 1 or more digits.
- `\]` - closing square bracket.

Comment: Yeah both of these answers work, but they are broken with white space [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sG8kM0/2)

Comment: Try with [`([A-Z]\w*\s*\S*)\[(\d+)?(?:\/(\d+))?\]`](https://regex101.com/r/jV4qS0/1).

Comment: Works with one white space, and if the name isn't capitalized it also breaks out, I feel like I'm just asking you to do this for me, I tried to use regex but I honestly have not dealt with anything with this much depth.

Comment: The problem is: what are the boundaries? Where we should start matching and where should we stop? Once you formulate that in words, we'll be able to provide a working answer. With what you say, we must match `Richard///[][][`, `12345`, `678910111213141516`, and then `was murdered by Ralph[/`, `54321`, `161514131211109876`.

Comment: Yeah but the variability is out of my control, the first part the name can be any alpha numerical characters and special characters with a minimum of two characters and any amount of whitespaces 32 character max, its a username on Steam.

Comment: Even if we consider the name starts with a non-whitespace, it will not be what you expect: [`(\b\S.{1,31})\[(\d+)?(?:\/(\d+))?\]`](https://regex101.com/r/jV4qS0/2). Are there any other boundaries? Note that there may be no 100% solution if your pattern cannot be defined. Now, it is just "match anything from 2 to 32 characters". And inside a free text input, it will always match more than you need.

Comment: It's not 100% but I can work around the discrepancies that I have found. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A possible regex solution would be to use a pattern like follows:

```
(\S+)\[(\d+)/(\d+)\](?:\s|$)
```

which will match and store the names (with their meta attributes). I am currently thinking of ways when it could break.

You can test it [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sG8kM0/1).